# How do I write a loop that goes through a column in chronological order, and outputs based on other columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am very new to coding and need some help!

[image: Sorry I don't know how to type dfs]

example df:
**A   B**
a   Good
b   Good
c   Good
c   Good
a   Good
b   Bad
c   Good
c   Good
a   Good
b   Good
c   Bad
c   Good
a   Good
b   Good
c   Good

desired output df:
**A   B       C**
a   Good    1
b   Good    1
c   Good    1
c   Good    1
a   Good    1
b   Bad     1
c   Good    1
d   Good    1
a   Good    2
b   Good    2
c   Bad     2
c   Good    2
a   Good    3
b   Good    3
c   Good    3

Basically if B is != Good and A is != c or d, then return n+1, but if it is then continue with n until is != c or d.

In plain english, once the value in column B is not "good", check column A to see if it is not c or d. If it is c or d, continue with the running sum, but once it changes to a value that is not c or d, then add 1 to the running sum and print into column C.

Comment: It sounds like column C depends on value of column C. Please try to express the problem with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing what you want here... Using [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df = df.assign(
    C=np.where((df["B"].ne("Good") & ~df["A"].isin(["c", "d"])), df["C"] + 1, df["C"])
)
print(df)

    A     B  C
0   a  Good  1
1   b  Good  1
2   c  Good  1
3   c  Good  1
4   a  Good  1
5   b   Bad  2
6   c  Good  1
7   c  Good  1
8   a  Good  2
9   b  Good  2
10  c   Bad  2
11  c  Good  2
12  a  Good  3
13  b  Good  3
14  c  Good  3
```